# Graph theory, sitting around a table

Tags: graph-theory

14 guests attend to a dinner at which each knows at least 7 other guests. Show that persons can be placed around a table so that each guest knows both his table neighbors.

The problem should be solved by using graph theory.
So far, I have tried with "ores theorem".

***How to solve the above problem?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that if guest $u$ knows $v$, then $v$ also knows $u$. The following theorem about [Hamilton circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is well known.

> If a graph $G= (V, E)$ has $n \geq 3$ vertices and every vertex has degree $n / 2$, then $G$ has a Hamilton circuit.

In your problem, each guest is a vertex in $G$ and there is an edge between guests $u$ and $v$ if they know each other.

Comment: So it´s a Hamilton circuit since $deg(u)=7\geq{14/2}$ And then we have shown that the guests can be placed around a table so that each guest knows both his neighbours. @NP-hard

Comment: @user306874 Exactly.